# How to force a lit custom element to re-render

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, lit

I'm running into an issue in my project in which appending/re-appending my custom element causes some components in the shadowRoot to disappear.

Is there a way I can force the element to re-render itself? I've tried setting `display:none;` then `display:flex;` either immediately afterwards or after a timeout, I've tried using `requestUpdate()` with no success (and looking at the documentation, it may not be applicable here), and I've tried forcing a browser resize event as well. So far, nothing has re-rendered the element.

Is there a way to fully re-render a custom element using lit or plain typescript/javascript?

Comment: How are you "appending/re-appending" the element? Some reproducible code would help to determine what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Typically our implementations of `requestUpdate()` will trigger a render cycle, so I am not clear on the details of your particular implementation/challenges with it's use. But I will speak to some of my experiences triggering change detection/render cycles in hopes that you may find some of this information useful.

For example, `lit` purposely uses shallow change detection (for performance reasons I believe? I could be wrong), so, changing a deeply nested key value pair in a complex object will not trigger change detection/render cycles.

So in these situations, we use either the `@state` decorator on internal data objects if we want changes of that data to trigger change detection, but not expose it externally, or, if it's is a public property via `@property` decorator, then it already has the change detection built in.

So for demonstration purposes, say you have either a `@state` or `@property` variable that looks something like this.

```
  @state() private sampleState: {
    testData: {
      shouldTriggerChangeDetection: boolean
    }
  } = {
      testData: {
        shouldTriggerChangeDetection: false
      }
    };
```

A simple adjustment of `shouldTriggerChangeDetection` value from `false` to `true` like below will not trigger a change detection/render cycle.

```
this.sampleState.testData.shouldTriggerChangeDetection = true;
```

In the above scenario you would absolutely need to leverage `requestUpdate()` like this.

```
this.sampleState.testData.shouldTriggerChangeDetection = true;

this.requestUpdate().then(() => {
        /* do something interesting after render is complete */
    });
```

We have had success using the above pattern to trigger change detection/render cycles, but, there is also another alternative that we have began to leverage by implementing the use of a spread operator to force `lit` change detection/render cycles via deep copy.

That would look something like this.

```
this.sampleState = {
    ...this.sampleState,
    ...{ testData: { shouldTriggerChangeDetection: true } }
};
```

Because the above approach generates a "deep" copy of the object, it will force `lit` change detection and ultimately a render cycle.

Keep in mind that these scenarios are presented from the perspective of having business logic inside of the web component that needs to force change detection/render cycles from the inside out... but the spread operator approach can be utilized from outside of the web component to force change detection/render cycles via forcing a deep copy of the object that is passed in to the property binding on the selector.

I hope this information helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Check your element's lifecycle callbacks: Ensure that you have implemented the necessary lifecycle callbacks correctly, such as render(), updated(), or shouldUpdate(). These callbacks play a crucial role in updating and rendering the component correctly.

Comment: I have `render()` and `willUpdate()` implemented, but would `willUpdate()`/`updated()`/`shouldUpdate()` even be relevant if there are no properties that have changed? The only thing that has changed is the custom elements location in the DOM

Comment: Is this a ChatGPT answer